# Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Uri' Brocade switch FOS REST API

Tags: powershell, rest, automation, storage, san

```
$Auth = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("<username>:<password>") 
$Basic = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($Auth) 

add-type @"
    using System.Net;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
        public bool CheckValidationResult(
            ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
            WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
            return true;
        }
    }
"@
$AllProtocols = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12'

[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $AllProtocols

[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Ssl3, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true} ;

$Header = @{ 
  'Accept' = 'application/yang-data+json' 
  'Content-Type' = 'application/yang-data+json' 
  'Authorization' = "Basic $Basic"
}

$InvokeParam = @{ 
  'Uri' = 'https://10.xx.xx.xx/rest/login' 
  'Method' = 'POST' 
  'Headers' = $Header
} 

$Response = Invoke-WebRequest @InvokeParam | ConvertTo-Json

$Authkey = $Response.headers.Authorization
```

I am entering the username and password of the brocade switch. The same credentials are used for ssh.

Basically I am trying to run a brocade command. I am calling the api using Powershell Invoke-WebRequest. I am doing this for the first time using powershell.

I am getting below error:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : Unable to connect to the remote server
At C:\Users\kashyupa\Documents\Untitled2.ps1:37 char:13
+ $Response = Invoke-WebRequest @InvokeParam  | ConvertTo-Json
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [In 
   voke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Invo 
   keWebRequestCommand
 
The variable '$Response' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
At C:\Users\kashyupa\Documents\Untitled2.ps1:40 char:12
+ $Authkey = $Response.headers.Authorization
+            ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Response:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableIsUndefined
```

```
sw0:FADA28:testuser> mgmtapp --show
REST Interface State: Enabled
REST Session Count: 3
REST Throttling Configurations:
   Sample Requests      : 30
   Sample Time (in sec) : 30
   Idle Time (in sec)   : 3
KeepAlive : Disabled
KeepAliveTimeout : 15sec
```

Comment: Your variable is named ```$InvokeParam``` but you’re splatting ```@InvokeParams```. Is that a typo in your post, or in the original code? (I’d recommend enabling strict mode - ```Set-StrictMode -Version “Latest”``` if it doesn’t generate too many issues with your existing code - it gives more descriptive errors about variables not being defined before use)

Comment: @mclayton yes that was a typo in the code. I ran this command Set-StrictMode -Version “Latest” and now I am getting "Unable to connect to the remote server".  I have added this error on the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem in this code. The issue is with https. https is not enabled. To enable https on brocade switch I followed the steps given on this document: chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/FOS-82x-AG

Pre-Reqs: To use the recommended HTTPS protocol, a valid security certificate must be installed on the switch and the HTTPS protocol must be enabled on the switch before beginning REST operations. Refer to the Brocade Fabric OS Administration Guide for instructions on both these actions.